# Joining two queries having same kind of joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries. Both differs in only one join condition. Is there any way to make it a single query .Below are the queries.

First Query:

```
delete from Employee where Employee_ID in    
  (    
    select PK from Dept    
     inner join Tran on Tran.PK = Dept.TX_ID   
        inner join TASK on TASK.TRANSINFO = TRAN.PK_ID   
        inner join TASK1 on TASK.PT_ID = TASK1.PK_ID  
           inner join TASKSUB on TASKSUB.PK_ID = TASK1.SUBJECT   
  where TASKSUB. PK1 in (select id  from tmp) and TASKSUB.REF= ‘Shopping’
  );
```

Second Query:

```
    delete from Employee where Employee_ID in   
      (   
  select PK from Dept   
    inner join Tran on Tran.PK = Dept.TX_ID   
     inner join TASK on TASK.TRANSINFO = TRAN.PK_ID   
      inner join TASK1 on TASK.PT_ID = TASK1.PK_ID   
         inner join TASKSUB on TASKSUB.PK_ID = TASK1.SUBJECT   
  where TASKSUB. PK1 in (select id1  from tmp) and TASKSUB.REF= ‘Shopping’   
  );
```

The only difference is id and id1 in tmp table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a `UNION` in the sub select for id and id1. Something like

```
select id from table1 
union 
select id1 from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from Employee where Employee_ID in    
(    
select PK from Dept    
 inner join Tran on Tran.PK = Dept.TX_ID   
    inner join TASK on TASK.TRANSINFO = TRAN.PK_ID   
    inner join TASK1 on TASK.PT_ID = TASK1.PK_ID  
       inner join TASKSUB on TASKSUB.PK_ID = TASK1.SUBJECT   
where TASKSUB. PK1 in (select id from tmp union all select id1 from tmp) and TASKSUB.REF= ‘Shopping’
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
delete from Employee where Employee_ID in    
(    
    select PK from Dept    
    inner join Tran on Tran.PK = Dept.TX_ID   
    inner join TASK on TASK.TRANSINFO = TRAN.PK_ID   
    inner join TASK1 on TASK.PT_ID = TASK1.PK_ID  
    inner join TASKSUB on TASKSUB.PK_ID = TASK1.SUBJECT   
    where TASKSUB. PK1 in (select id  from tmp) and TASKSUB.REF= ‘Shopping’

    union

    select PK from Dept   
    inner join Tran on Tran.PK = Dept.TX_ID   
    inner join TASK on TASK.TRANSINFO = TRAN.PK_ID   
    inner join TASK1 on TASK.PT_ID = TASK1.PK_ID   
        inner join TASKSUB on TASKSUB.PK_ID = TASK1.SUBJECT   
    where TASKSUB. PK1 in (select id1  from tmp) and TASKSUB.REF= ‘Shopping’
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
where EXISTS (
        select 1 from tmp 
        where TASKSUB.PK1 = tmp.id or TASKSUB.PK1 = tmp.id1
    ) and 
    TASKSUB.REF= ‘Shopping’
```